# Switch to Intel Iris Pro on MacBook Pro under Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, gpu

After a successful installation of Windows (Windows Server 2012 R2) on a MacBook Pro (Late 2013, 15") I've noticed that only the Nvidia graphics card is recognized in the device manager. So I've tried to install setup.exe from the folder `IntelHDGraphics64` which I found on the installation disk created with BootCamp, but I got this error:

```
"This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software."
```

Same error message was thrown when I tried to install the latest drivers from Intel directly.
I even tried to install the drivers manually, but this didn't work either.

Now I would like to know whether it is even possible to get the Intel Iris Pro graphics card running on a MacBook under Windows and then switch between them to increase battery life when I don't need high graphics peformance.

I am using the Mavericks version of BootCamp assistant and have the retina model.

Comment: I have installed Windows Server (various versions) on multiple machines running Intel integrated graphics (from HD2000 up) and have really struggled to find drivers for them. As these are servers, I have generally left them without drivers as the built-in MS drivers suffice. I have not seen any evidence of Intel releasing the drivers.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear, but unfortunately there is no way to disable the discrete GPU and use the integrated graphics, when using Bootcamp.

This has been discussed (to death) on support forums and on the web generally.

I have thought myself in the past, that it would be useful to be able to turn off the discrete GPU just to improve battery life on the laptop. But Apple have not provided a driver capable of switching off the discrete GPU, so there is no way of doing it.

Sorry to be the bringer of bad news - who knows, maybe they will provide that functionality in the future?

Comment: This answer I've seen on many forums I looked through, but I still had the hope to find a possibility. ;) It would also be interesting to know why Apple does not provide this functionality. The only reasons I can think of is to annoy Windows user and force them to go back to MacOS...

Comment: I would not assume it's because they are feeling vindictive - I would rather assume that they did not want to write their own drivers for the chipset, that include functionality for switching it off. My assumption is that they are using the standard driver for the discrete GPU anyway. They probably don't even have the source code for the Windows driver for the GPU, and would either have to write one from scratch (ouch), or get the manufacturer to do it for them. For each manufacturer, and every chipset they have ever used in a laptop. And then get them certified (WHQL). Not so worth it, really

Comment: But what if one buys MBPr without external GPU. In this case is Windows able to use the Iris graphics? What is the battery life in this case?

Comment: If you have a MacBook Pro with only one graphics card then it will use that graphics card, and there are drivers for it in the Boot Camp Support stuff you download from Apple. The problem is that if there are two cards, Windows doesn't know how to switch between them.

Comment: So then can I choose to only use the iris pro on windows then? I value battery life over performance. If i have the choice between only using one of the gpus i'd like it to be the iris pro.

Comment: Re-read the answer: "there is no way to disable the discrete GPU and use the integrated graphics, when using Bootcamp." If you have the integrated graphics and a discrete GPU, Windows running under Bootcamp will always use the discrete GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst possible with Windows 8, it's not a task for the faint hearted.

There's a guide here:

http://forum.techinferno.com/implementation-guides-apple/8717-%5Bguide%5D-enabling-intel-iris-pro-hd5200-win8-1-15-macbook-pro-gt750m.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even thought it's a rather old thread, it's still one of the first that come up if you are searching for I-Gpu and MacBook Pro.

In any case, it seems that it is possible to activate the igpu on windows, by following this guide: 
[guide 1](https://egpu.io/forums/mac-setup/how-to-keep-mbps-irisiris-pro-activated-when-booting-into-windows-boot-camp/)
[guide 2](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh)

What you are basically doing, is spoofing the system thinking that you are booting on MacOS while you are booting on windows. It seems that it's mostly an issue on people that are interested on using an egpu on windows, but it was also a problem for anyone that doesn't work the battery to last for like 2-3 hours when using windows because of the dedicated gpu running all the time.

I have successfully installed it on my computer and is working without any problems.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't disable the GPU, you can, I have to do it because my graphics card is failing (2011 iMac). It's that there is no other option but the default graphics driver provided by Windows (VGASave). I would be fine with that option but VGAsave only has a few resolutions, and it stretches them to fit your screen. Again I have used it for a while without the stretching (just has black bars) and it is a thousand times better than VGAsave. I'm sure it would not be overly difficult to implement a non-stretched alternative.

I know it's hard to think of Apple's philosophy being bad, especially since it is the same philosophy that has bought so many good things. But it's obviously because they want you to have the best performance all the time. And if you can't get that then you need to get a new machine.